# Reading strings one by one from a file and adding them to a linked list

Tags: c, string, file, text

I am trying to read the strings from a text file one by one and add them to a linked list. Nodes contain the string itself and the number of the occurrences of the string in the file. So every string will be added the linked list only once, if linked list already has the string, **int num** variable in node should be incremented by one. **Using arrays is forbidden.**

```
typedef struct node
{
    char *word;
    int num;
    struct node *next;
} node;

node* addToHead(node *head, char word[])
{
    if(Contains(head, word) == 0)
    {
        node *tmp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        tmp->word = (char)malloc((sizeof(char)* strlen(word) + sizeof(char)));
        tmp->word = word;
        tmp->num = 1;

        if(head == NULL)
        {
            tmp->next = NULL;
            head = tmp;
        }
    }
    return head;
}
node* add(node *head, char word[])
{
    if(Contains(head, word) == 0)
    {
        node *iter = head;
        node *tmp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        tmp->word = (char)malloc((sizeof(char)* strlen(word) + sizeof(char)));
        tmp->word = word;
        tmp->num = 1;
        if(head != NULL)
        {
            while(iter->next != NULL)
                iter = iter->next;

            iter->next = tmp;
            tmp->next = NULL;
            return head;

        }
        else if(head == NULL)
        {
            head = addToHead(head, word);
            return head;
        }

    }
 return head;
}
int Contains(node *head, char word[])
{
    node *iter = head;
    while(iter!= NULL)
    {
        if(strcmp(iter->word, word) == 0)
        {
            iter->num++;
            return 1;
        }
        iter = iter->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
void printList(node *head)
{
    node *iter = head;
     while(iter!=NULL)
    {
        printf("word: %s || number of word: %d\n", iter->word, iter->num);
        iter=iter->next;
    }
}
   int main()
   {
        node *head=NULL;


    FILE* file= fopen("text.txt", "r");
    char word[500];

    for(int i = 0; fscanf(file, "%s", word) != EOF; i++)
    {

        head = add(head, word);

        printList(head);

    }
    printList(head);




    return 0;
}
```

In this code, i rewrite the linked list every time I add a new string to linked list. As far as I can tell, it doesn't generate a new node but rewrites the word on the previously added word. C**ommas and dots are not a problem.** I wrote same Lorem Ipsum paragraph 3 times. Output is like:

[image]

How will I create a single node for each word while reading words from the file?

Comment: Hm. Your problem is where you assign the string. You allocate memory with `malloc` and in the next instruction you assign the pointer that holds the allocated memory to `word`. That means (a) that you no longer have access to the allocated memory, which is a memory leak and (b) that all have the same data, nealy whatever is written in the line buffer, if it is still "alive". C is quite explicit and after allocating enough bytes for the string length and the terminator, you should `strcpy` the string into that memory.

Comment: You may have heard that in C, you shouldn't cast the result of `malloc`. C++ requires the cast, so some people do it anyway. But what you definitely don't want to do is to cast a pointer to a `char` -- you will try to store a 64-bit value in 8 bits, which is a recipe for disaster. Lose the cast and while you're at it, replace the `sizeof(char)` with 1, too. You'll be good and have a nice, short `malloc(strlen(word) + 1));`

Comment: OMG thank you very much. strcpy() solved all my problems.

Comment: *Using arrays is forbidden.*  Well, you're going to have a problem storing strings then.  Strings are nothing more than an array of `char` where the last `char` has the value of `'\0'`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Allocating memory and storing data in it (forming a string) does not truly make an _array_.  OTOH, `printf("word: %s || number of word: %d\n"` does use an _array_.  In any case, "Using arrays is forbidden." is a reflection on a weak assignment emphasizing the wrong ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed above there are a couple of issues with your code:

1. `tmp->word = (char)malloc((sizeof(char)* strlen(word) + sizeof(char)));`. Malloc returns a pointer to the address that is allocated hence you should be writing:
   `tmp->word = (char *)malloc((sizeof(char)* strlen(word) + sizeof(char)));`
2. This is the reason why you're not getting the expected output: `tmp->word = word;`, by doing this even-though you allocate a new node it's word field points to the current word. Thus when you read a word in the loop you are changing `head->word` accidentally. So you should be doing this in this manner `strcpy(tmp->word, word)`.

I've added the corrected code as well for your reference.

```
#include<stdio.h>
typedef struct node
{
    char *word;
    int num;
    struct node *next;
} node;

node* addToHead(node *head, char word[])
{
    if(Contains(head, word) == 0)
    {
        node *tmp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        //tmp->word = (char)malloc((sizeof(char)* strlen(word) + sizeof(char)));
        //tmp->word = word;
        tmp->word = (char *)malloc((sizeof(char)* strlen(word) + sizeof(char)));
        strcpy(tmp->word, word);
        tmp->num = 1;

        if(head == NULL)
        {
            tmp->next = NULL;
            head = tmp;
        }
    }
    return head;
}
node* add(node *head, char word[])
{
    if(Contains(head, word) == 0)
    {
        node *iter = head;
        node *tmp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        //tmp->word = (char)malloc((sizeof(char)* strlen(word) + sizeof(char)));
        //tmp->word = word;
        tmp->word = (char *)malloc((sizeof(char)* strlen(word) + sizeof(char)));
        strcpy(tmp->word, word);
        tmp->num = 1;
        if(head != NULL)
        {
            while(iter->next != NULL)
                iter = iter->next;

            iter->next = tmp;
            tmp->next = NULL;
            return head;

        }
        else if(head == NULL)
        {
            head = addToHead(head, word);
            return head;
        }

    }
 return head;
}
int Contains(node *head, char word[])
{
    node *iter = head;
    while(iter!= NULL)
    {
        if(strcmp(iter->word, word) == 0)
        {
            iter->num++;
            return 1;
        }
        iter = iter->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
void printList(node *head)
{
    node *iter = head;
     while(iter!=NULL)
    {
        printf("word: %s || number of word: %d\n", iter->word, iter->num);
        iter=iter->next;
    }
}
   int main()
   {
        node *head=NULL;


    FILE* file= fopen("text.txt", "r");
    char word[500];

    for(int i = 0; fscanf(file, "%s", word) != EOF; i++)
    {

        head = add(head, word);

        printList(head);


    }
    printList(head);




    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested with a fixed sized array of 6 strings, your codes work correctly and the printed output is as expect :

```
int main()
{
    node *head=NULL;
    char * word[6] = {"Alpha", "Beta", "Alpha", "Teta", "Alpha", "Beta"};

    for(int i = 0; i<6; i++)
    {
        head = add(head, word[i]);
    }
    printList(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Output :

```
word: Alpha || number of word: 3
word: Beta  || number of word: 2
word: Teta  || number of word: 1
```

So, as explained in comments, the issue seems to be rather in the way you allocate those strings and/or read them from the file.